# Easiest free email server for Windows development

Tags: windows, email, testing

I'm developing a Java app on the Windows platform, and my application needs to send email.  For development/testing purposes, what is an easy and free email server I can run on Windows?

Comment: I think you are asking about an SMTP client, not a server.

Comment: I think this question has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385076/a-clean-lightweight-mail-server-for-test/7590238#7590238 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177990/local-smtp-server-that-can-be-used-for-testing-and-development-wont-actually-d/7590181#7590181

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not running the low-end Home edition of Windows then there is a SMTP server built in (Install IIS and components).

But maybe you want a 'fake' server, one that only pretends to forward mail. Look for [Dumbster](http://quintanasoft.com/dumbster/) or the .NET port NDumbster

Answer (score 0):

I have had good luck with [MailEnable](http://www.mailenable.com/). It's free and fairly easy to set up.