# Local SMTP server that can be used for testing and development - won't actually deliver mail

Tags: windows-7, smtp

When I'm developing something that sends email, I sometimes don't want to actually send any email, but I do want to see what email would be sent using live data. However, there's not an easy way to do this, as I haven't found a local SMTP server that will receive my mail and then just hold it for me in a queue so I can view it.

In Windows XP and Vista, I used the locally installed SMTP server and just set it to deliver to a smart host that didn't exist - the mail just sat in the "inetput\mailroot\queue" folder forever, and I could view it whenever I wanted to. However, in Windows 7, there's no longer an integrated SMTP server, and though I've found a number of SMTP servers that can be installed locally and relay mail for me, I want one that **won't** relay mail.

Does anybody have suggestions on how to accomplish this functionality? I've considered writing my own, but implementing the whole RFC spec seemed like a big task if there's something out there. Maybe there's an open-source project that I could modify just to write the mail to disk instead of delivering it.

Comment: Mailnest.io is an affordable solution as it helps in collaboration between teams or it has a free plan if your usage is less.

Comment: For testing purpose [fake-smtp-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fake-smtp-server) is very useful. One line command to start the server `fake-smtp-server [OPTIONS] [ARGS]`

Answer (score 182, accepted):

[Papercut](https://github.com/changemakerstudios/papercut) is likely what you want, though it is **only compatible with Windows**.

Comment: That couldn't be more what was I was looking for if I'd written the spec myself - thanks for the tip!

Comment: How to use it? I don't get it.

Comment: @Emerald214: Download the application and run it. It will set up an SMTP server when it's running. Configure your application to use 'localhost' (or the machine where the server is running) as the SMTP server. If you need to use a non-default port number, you can configure it in Options.

Comment: Can't begin to tally the hours i've wasted trying to setup relays with my personal gmail account.  This is the solution and I wish it were better known. Thank you driis!!

Comment: Umm, what about non-Windows environments?

Comment: @Brade, first google hit: http://nilhcem.github.io/FakeSMTP/

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion! I wanted to test email notifications sent by JIRA! This did the trick for me!

Comment: To clarify the above, use Host: localhost, Port: 25 (default that can be changed)

Comment: Simple, but very useful tool. Just be aware that a) the GUI client tends to crash in my UAT-VM because the environment can't access the Internet, and the first sample email automatically generated includes external resources (you can delete the mail file from the "Incoming" folder), and b) if you copy the unzipped files to, say, "C:\Program Files" and run from there, you'll need to run the program as admin or it won't be able to do things like delete its emails.

Comment: smtp4dev - windows only - http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Servers/E-mail-Servers/smtp4dev.shtml

Comment: I SO love both this question and this answer... I always forget the name of this great solution. Thanks for having it here. Do understand why the Stack thinks this is not a good question.

Answer (score 12):

Another local test SMTP server application:
https://nilhcem.github.io/FakeSMTP/

Comment: This one is based on Java and somewhat platform independant.

Comment: what should be username and password for this server? I am getting error message 504 The requested authentication mechanism is not supported

Answer (score 4):

Awesome, free, cross-platform, and even runs well in a VM environment like Vagrant: http://mailcatcher.me/

Comment: for mac users only

Comment: @NicoToub What makes you say that? You'll need to install Ruby, but it should run on Windows.

Comment: You are right, it is packaged only on mac but can run on linux & windows if you manage how to install it.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at [NDdumbster](http://ndumbster.sourceforge.net/default.html)