# A Clean lightweight Mail Server for Test

Tags: email, testing, open-source

I need a Mail Server to test an application that send and receive emails.

So it should:

- be lightweight and small in size
- be free (like free beer), open source preferred
- support Win XP
- support SMTP, IMAP (POP3 is optional)
- install clean

Plz:

- Don't suggest connecting to Gmail, its ports are blocked.
- Don't suggest testing frameworks.

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to have SMTP and IMAP in the same server, especially if you want it to be small and easy to configure.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177990/local-smtp-server-that-can-be-used-for-testing-and-development-wont-actually-d

Comment: http://www.xmailserver.org/                                      http://p-nand-q.com/download/shicks.html

Comment: @AlexK xmailserver and shicks sound good but have not IMAP support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about hMailServer: http://www.hmailserver.com/

It includes SMTP, POP3, IMAP servers

Answer (score 4):

I'm rather fond of [Papercut](http://papercut.codeplex.com/). It only does SMTP, but it can run without administrator privileges.