# how to send emails from localhost in codeigniter xampp windows

Tags: php, windows, email, codeigniter, xampp

xampp , and codeigniter , i want to send emails from my localhost .

in ubuntu i can create an Email server very easily by

```
$ sudo apt-get install sendmail
```

and update the configuration in application/frontend/config/email.php

```
$config['useragent']           = "CodeIgniter";
$config['mailpath']            = "/usr/bin/sendmail"; // or "/usr/sbin/sendmail"
$config['protocol']            = "mail";
$config['smtp_host']           = "localhost";
$config['smtp_user']           = "";
$config['smtp_pass']           = "";
$config['smtp_port']           = "25";
```

i want to setup `sendmail` in windows , how can i do this ?? please help . search a lot , but could not find a working solution .

Comment: There *are* working solutions for this, it's just harder than on Linux... But can't you use an on-line SMTP server instead? Mails from dynamic IPs get eaten by most spam filters anyway.

Comment: @Pekka plese can you explain me a bit . how do i use an online SMTP server ? i tried changing php.ini                                  SMTP = smtp.wlink.com.np
smtp_port = 25 , but not working

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to set up a mail server on Windows. You'll need a separate product for that,  see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857617/easiest-free-email-server-for-windows-development) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385076/a-clean-lightweight-mail-server-for-test/7590238#7590238). [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html#644) comes with a mail server bundled.

However, using a local mail server is rarely wise. Mails coming from a dynamic IP address tend to get swallowed by spam filters, as anybody can do this from any internet connection. It's better to use the SMTP server that is serving the domain name you want to use as the sender domain.

My favourite solution for that is [SwiftMailer.](http://www.swiftmailer.org) It's a replacement for the `mail()` command and comes with many options. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478906/using-phps-swiftmailer-with-gmail) is an example on how to make it work with GMail.

SwiftMailer doesn't work with the  `mail()` command though: You'll have to change your PHP code to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

I remember using [**BLAT**](http://www.blat.net/), a command line mailer for windows. Dead simple install and usage, providing that you have an SMTP account avalaible. I would recommend this over setting up your own server.

It does not however replace `mail()` directly, nor is a mail server *per se*, so YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Use a service like authsmtp.com or gridsend.com. I find that these work well for tracking outbound email activity, managing spam boxes, plus you don't have to worry about a different sending environment on your local machine than your production environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try **minirelay**. Quite easy to use and works fine.
http://www.blat.net/miniRelay/